# Overloading << with ostream and an enum type

Tags: c++, oop, enums, operator-overloading

Following is my code. I am trying to print an enumerated data type variable, one directly which its name and another with a function with returns the same data type as the original variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
enum days{SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT};


inline days dayaftertomorrow(days d)
{
  return static_cast<days>((static_cast<int>(d) + 2) % 7);
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, days& day)
{
  switch(day)
  {
    case SUN: out << "SUN"; break;
    case MON: out << "MON"; break;
    case TUE: out << "TUE"; break;
    case WED: out << "WED"; break;
    case THU: out << "THU"; break;
    case FRI: out << "FRI"; break;
    case SAT: out << "SAT"; break;
  }
  return out;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  days d = MON, e;
  e = dayaftertomorrow(d);
  cout << d << "\t" << e << endl;
  cout << d << "\t" << dayaftertomorrow(d) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I expect the result as

```
MON     WED
MON     WED
```

But I am getting

```
MON     WED
MON     3
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Use `enum class days` instead of `enum days` : the use of `enum class` inhibits implicit conversions to an integral type. This way you'd get an error instead of the compiler circumventing your overloaded operator as it doesn't match a temporary object (you'd need to take `days const&` as parameter instead of `days&`: the latter only binds to a [modifyable] lvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `operator<<` is taking parameter `day` by reference to non-const. `dayaftertomorrow` returns by value; what `dayaftertomorrow` returns is a temporary which can't be bound to reference to non-const. Then for `cout << dayaftertomorrow(d)`, your `operator<<` won't be invoked, the enumerator will be [implicitly converted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to `int` and then printed out via [std::basic_ostream::operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) instead; that's why you got `3`.

To solve the issue you could change the parameter type to reference to `const`; which could bind to the temporary. Or change it to pass-by-value. e.g.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const days& day)
//                                 ~~~~~

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, days day)
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vmEnn1AoZVFoaFtM)